# Is it possible to append a react component to body

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am importing a react component from npm

```
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';
```

Right now to use a color picker I write the following method in my class component

```
 colorHandler(value) {
    if (value === 'custom-color') {
      var picker = document.getElementById('color-picker');
      if (!picker) {
        picker = document.createElement('input');
        picker.id = 'color-picker';
        picker.type = 'color';
        picker.style.display = 'none';
        picker.value = '#FF0000';
        document.body.appendChild(picker);

        picker.addEventListener(
          'change',
          () => {
            this.quill.format('color', picker.value);
          },
          false,
        );
      }
      picker.click();
    } else {
      this.quill.format('color', value);
    }
  }
```

I would basically like something like

```
var picker = document.getElementById('color-picker');
picker.appendChild(<SketchPicker />)
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent />, document.getElementById('color-picker'))`. This is your entry point, do not call `render` multiple times, only in your root component, and if you're using `create-react-app` or `next` this is already configured. https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

Comment: This would not work as I already use ReactDOM to render my app. I get the following error if I try - Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: If you  really need to insert jsx into a specific node take a look at  [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). This is not common but is a legitimate usecase